# Simpliest way for buttons on jq-bootgrid with rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-bootgrid

I want to create a table, with buttons using jq-bootgrid. Bootgrid itself works great, but I've read on their page (examples), that if I want to make edit/destroy buttons I need to use some javascript. I think I know how to do it this way (found answer on stack). But the thing is, I should avoid using javascript, and use it only when necessary (we don't like javascript here). So, is it necessary here? Or maybe there is some workaround?

And one additional question.

```
<%= link_to 'button', model_path(model) %>
```

Why something like this is not working? There is only "button" word being shown, but it is not a link.
On the other hand, showing the path using

```
<%= model_path(model) %>
```

works perfectly. Why it does not work together?